Does Blood Pump count as both a Health Item and Cyberware?
I am currently using Blood Pump in my build, and am wondering if it would count as both Cyberware and a Health item, and thus benefit from buffs that apply to both.
For example, would getting a kill while using the Newton Module/Axolotl Cyberware reduce the cooldown of my Blood Pump along with gear with +X% to Health Item Recharge Speed?

Apparently there's a lot of confusion about this topic.
I found this on Reddit:

Does the Axolotl cooldown reduction apply to Blood Pump?


Yes, it reduces the cooldown of blood pump charges. Actually I've never noticed. It explains why my character felt so broken with Axolotl.

While this is from Steam Community:

Is Blood Pump cyberware counted as "cyberware" for cooldown with Newton Module/Axolotl?


Nope. I did a lot of testing on that. It's only a health item in regards to duration and cooldown.


Alright, guess I will have to test it out myself once I get access to it on this run lol

I wonder if something got patched along the way; there's about a month's difference between the posts with the "no" answer being later. When was the last hotfix/patch for CP2077?
